# Как работает этот код JavaScript?

Tags: xml, javascript, html

Добрый вечер, вот есть вот такой код JavaScript:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xul="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

<head>
    <script>
        < ![CDATA[
        var dx, dy;
        var circle;

        function init() {
            circle = document.getElementById('circ');
            circle.addEventListener("mousedown", mousedown_listener, false);
        }

        function mousedown_listener(evt) {
            dx = circle.cx.baseVal.value - evt.clientX;
            dy = circle.cy.baseVal.value - evt.clientY;
            document.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove_listener, true);
            document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup_listener, true);
        }

        function mouseup_listener(evt) {
            document.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemove_listener, true);
            document.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseup_listener, true);
        }

        function mousemove_listener(evt) {
            var id = circle.ownerSVGElement.suspendRedraw(1000);
            circle.cx.baseVal.value = evt.clientX + dx;
            circle.cy.baseVal.value = evt.clientY + dy;
            // alternatively we could set the corresponding attributes:
            // (slower method)
            //      circle.setAttribute("cx", evt.clientX + dx);
            //      circle.setAttribute("cy", evt.clientY + dy);
            circle.ownerSVGElement.unsuspendRedraw(id);
        }

        ]] >
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="init();">
    <h3>SVG + event handler demo</h3>
    <p>Drag the circle with the mouse!</p>
    <svg:svg width="600px" height="400px">
        <svg:polyline points="0,0 600,0 600,400 0,400 0,0" style="stroke:black; fill:none;" />
        <svg:circle id="circ" r="1cm" cx="5cm" cy="3cm" style="fill:red; stroke:blue; stroke-width:3;" /></svg:svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, как он работает. Заранее благодарен за любую помощь. Вот [тут](http://croczilla.com/bits_and_pieces/svg/samples/events2/events2.xml) наглядный пример работы этого кода.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> не понятен JavaScript, так как я изначально учил jQuery...

Может так станет понятнее:

#### js:

```
circle = document.getElementById('circ');
circle.addEventListener("mousedown", mousedown_listener, false);
```

#### jQuery:

```
circle = $('#circle');
circle.on("mousedown", mousedown_listener);
```

---

#### js:

```
dx = circle.cx.baseVal.value - evt.clientX;
dy = circle.cy.baseVal.value - evt.clientY;
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove_listener, true);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup_listener, true);
```

#### jQuery:

```
dx = circle[0].cx.baseVal.value - evt.clientX;
dy = circle[0].cy.baseVal.value - evt.clientY;
$(document).on("mousemove", mousemove_listener);
$(document).on("mouseup", mouseup_listener);
```

---

#### js:

```
document.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemove_listener, true);
document.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseup_listener, true);
```

#### jQuery:

```
$(document).off("mousemove", mousemove_listener);
$(document).off("mouseup", mouseup_listener);
```

---

#### js:

```
var id = circle.ownerSVGElement.suspendRedraw(1000);
circle.cx.baseVal.value = evt.clientX + dx;
circle.cy.baseVal.value = evt.clientY + dy;
circle.ownerSVGElement.unsuspendRedraw(id);
```

#### jQuery:

```
var id = circle[0].ownerSVGElement.suspendRedraw(1000);
circle[0].cx.baseVal.value = evt.clientX + dx;
circle[0].cy.baseVal.value = evt.clientY + dy;
circle[0].ownerSVGElement.unsuspendRedraw(id);
```

- [element.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener)
- [element.removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.removeEventListener)

Comment: Огромное, Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

А что именно не понятно?

Грубо говоря, при загрузки документа на объект с `id =circ` вешается обработчик события нажатия мыши `mousedown_listener`, который также вешает события на отпускании кнопки мыши над объектом `function mouseup_listener(evt)`, и передвижении `function mousemove_listener(evt)`.

Comment: не понятен JavaScript, так как я изначально учил jQuery...

Comment: Скоро наверно JavaScript будет считаться низкоуровневым языком.

Comment: те, кто юзают `CoffeScript` уже так считают